# Is it possible to delete the login and register pages? shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Is it possible to delete the login and register pages?

https://site.myshopify.com/account/login and https://site.myshopify.com/account/register

or you can remove the redirect to this page when you enter the wrong password on this form?

```
{% form 'customer_login', class:'form' %}
            <div class="title upper">вход</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="inputs">
                <input
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="E-mail"
                        name="customer[email]"
                        required
                        />
                <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Пароль"
                        name="customer[password]"
                        required
                        />
                </div>
                <div class="forget-password">
                    <button onclick="window.location='/pages/forgot-password'" type="button" class="pointer hv-green">
                        Забыли пароль?
                    </button>
                    {% if template.name == 'login' %}
                        <div class="error-message">
                            {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="login">
                <button type="submit" class="pointer upper">
                войти
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endform %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply disable customer accounts:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/customers/customer-accounts